# Parsing JSON with the TypedJSON (typedjson-npm)

Tags: angular

I'm using the Angular2.4 and want to parse JSON with the TypedJSON library (typedjson-npm). But I can't understand how to do it in the specific case that following.

I have the class for the JSON data, for example:

```
@JsonObject
export class UserModel {
  @JsomMember
  public 'name': string;
  @JsonMember
  public 'email': string;
  // I'm changing the name to have the one case-style for all properties, it's okay
  @JsonMember({ name: 'registration_date' })
  public 'registrationDate': string;
}
```

Then I have the JSON from the server like:

```
[
  {
    "name": "John",
    "email": "john@mail.com",
    "registration_date": "1497365370047"
  },
  {
    "name": "Mike",
    "email": "mike@mail.com",
    "registration_date": "1497365370047"
  }
]
```

Now I want to parse this JSON. I'm trying something like

```
this.http
    .get('http://zzzz.com/api/users-list')
    .subscribe((response: Response) => {
      let data: UserModel[] = TypedJSON.parse(response.json(), UserModel[]);
    });
```

But I see the error in the PHPStorm (red underline under last two symbols - ]) )

> Expression expected

I don't see any example in the documentation how to solve this problem.
So, my question is: how can I parse Array of the custom type Objects with this library?

Alternately, can someone recommend to me some npm library to use it within Angular2 that can simply replace property names like I noticed above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this we need to loop through the each json data,

Try this :

```
this.http
    .get('http://zzzz.com/api/users-list')
    .subscribe((response: Response) => {
      let resJson = response.json();
      let data: UserModel[] = resJson.map(res => TypedJSON.parse(res, UserModel); );
    });
```

Comment: Great , will you please accept answer and upvote it ?

Comment: I don't have enough of reputation to upvote, sadly :(

Comment: Okay no problem , then please just accept the answer. :)